# Python: Find list overlap with duplicates in lists

Tags: python

Lists being compared

```
list1 = ['Q, 'U', 'Z', 'Z']

List2 = ['Q, 'U', 'I', 'Z']
```

My query

```
common = []
for letter in list1: # QUZZ
    if letter in list2: # QUIZ --- this is the problematic condition (it is add 2 ZZ's instead of 1)
        common.append(letter)
print(common)
```

Expected Output

```
Common = ['Q, 'U', 'Z']
```

Actual Output

```
Common = ['Q, 'U', 'Z', 'Z']
```

To add, the query should also work for the reverse condition. I have tried using sets, but that doesn't work for the second condition

```
list1 = ['Z','Z','Z','Z','E','E']
list2= ['Z', 'Z', 'Z']


print(list(set([x for x in list1 if x in list2])))
```

Expected Output:
'''
['Z','Z','Z']

'''

Actual Output:

```
['Z']
```

Comment: Use `set` to remove the duplicates - `list(set([x for x in list1 if x in List2]))`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Or just `set(list1).intersection(list2)`

Comment: You could also use a counter for this if you want to preserve matching duplicates: `list((Counter(word1) & Counter(word2)).elements())`

Comment: @flakes thank you. I think the Counter solution will work -- giving it a shot. Was hoping there was an alternate to using collections

Comment: @ZibaJoon I wouldn't worry about using collections. That module is built into the core libraries (no pip required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `set` you can use the `&` operator, which for sets does an intersection. This will eliminate duplicates and find common elements.

Edit: For your problem you will actually need a multiset. I recommend using the `multiset` package which you can install with `pip install multiset` or `pip3 install multiset` if you're using python3.

```
from multiset import Multiset

list1 = ['Z','Z','Z','Z','E','E']

list2= ['Z', 'Z', 'Z']

print(Multiset(list1) & Multiset(list2)) # Output: {'Z', 'Z', 'Z'}
```

Comment: You don't need to create the second set: `set(list1).intersection(list2)`

Comment: @DeepSpace Looks good, added your method as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I tried using sets intersections earlier and found that it does not work for the reverse condition (have updated the content above).

Comment: @ZibaJoon I have updated my answer to handle this condition.

Answer (score 1):

As @It_is_Chris said in the comment you can use sets to remove duplicates. Sets also have a method to find common items:

```
list1 = ['Q, 'U', 'Z', 'Z']
list2 = ['Q, 'U', 'I', 'Z']
common = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))
```

The output is now a set, but can be converted to a list if needed.

Comment: You don't need to create the second set: `set(list1).intersection(list2)`